# How to use Nginx Regex in the location

Tags: nginx

For Nginx Location, How can I get the content in bold below?

https://proxyhost/**bucketname**/test/uid

```
location  ~* /regex/ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

I need use this regex to extract the bucket name and fill the real url in Nginx S3 proxy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering [Bucket naming rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html), here is a good start that covers these rules:

> - Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-).
> - Bucket names must begin and end with a letter or number.

```
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-\.]+[a-z0-9])/ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

or

```
location ~ ^/(?<bucket>([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-\.]+[a-z0-9]))/ {
    proxy_pass https://$bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```